# Как установить высоту изображения, точно равной ширине экрана, учитывая отступы?

Tags: android, изображения

У меня изображение по длине равно ширине экрана + отступ слева и справа. Высота wrap_content, очевидно, для какого-то экрана больше, для какого-то меньше – квадратным изображение не получится. Как можно установить высоту изображения, точно равной ширине экрана, учитывая отступы ?

P.S: Делать это нужно из фрагмента, а если в нем придется получать размеры экрана, то он вроде получается как-то по особенному, если не ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделай `ConstraintLayout` контейнером для `ImageView` и установи аттрибуты

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
```

Получишь `ImageView` с равными высотой и шириной